# Do there exist two-dimensional subspaces $W$ and $Y$ of $\mathbb{R^4},$ both invariant under $\alpha,$ such that $\mathbb{R^4} = W \oplus Y$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form, invariant-subspace

The question is given below:

> [image]

Could anyone give me a hint for solving the second part of the question?

Comment: suggest you write (typeset) the 4 by 4 matrix defined by $\alpha$ Your question is about the Jordan form of that matrix, you might as well have a visual

Comment: 1. Find the associated eigenspace of your eigenvalues. (It will be two-dimensional.)  2. Suppose there is a two-dimensional subspace, that is distinct from your eigenspace.  3. Using $\alpha$, you will either be able to create that subspace or find that one does not exist.

Comment: I think the answer given below is the best and should be accepted here. I don't have anything to offer, personally.

Comment: could you explain your approach more please @WillJagy? maybe in an answer if you do not mind

Comment: @WillJagy Pardon my ignorance. How would the Jordan form help? Not directly relevant, but to illustrate what I  don't get: Say $D=diag(1,1,0,0)$. Then $D$ has a lot of two-dimensional invariant subspaces in addition to the ones that are "visible" (to me) from looking at the JCF.

Comment: @Hotdog so the ordinary solution is by finding the eigenspace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Elegant Solution or Cryptic Hint, depending on who's reading:

> > **Previous.**  If $T:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$ is linear and $T^3=0$ then $T^2=0$.

Proof: The minimal polynomial $m(x)$ is a factor of $x^3$, while Cayley-Hamilton shows $\deg(m)\le 2$.

Now since $\alpha^3=0$, if $\Bbb R^4$ were the sum of invariant subspaces of dimension $2$ it would follow that $\alpha^2=0$, which is not so.

### Detailed Version

> > **Previous.**  If $T:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$ is linear and $T^3=0$ then $T^2=0$.

Proof: Say $m$ is the minimal polynomial for $T$. By definition $m$ is a non-constant monic polynomial, and if $p$ is any polynomial with $p(T)=0$ then $m$ divides $p$. Since $T^3=0$ this shows that $m$ is either $x$, $x^2$ or $x^3$.

Now say $p$ is the characteristic polynomial of $T$. Then $p$ is quadratic, and $p(T)=0$ implies $m$ divides $p$. So $m$ is $x$ or $x^2$. So either $T=0$ or $T^2=0$, and in either case it follows that $T^2=0$.

> > **Answer to the Question:** No.

Note first that $\alpha^2\ne0$ but $\alpha^3=0$.

Now suppose that $\Bbb R^4$ *is* the sum of two invariant subspaces $X$ and $Y$, each of dimension $2$. Define $$T:X\to X$$ by $$Tx=\alpha x.$$ That is, $T$ is the restriction of $\alpha$ to $X$. Now $\alpha^3=0$ shows that $T^3=0$, and since $X$ has dimension $2$ the previous result shows that in fact $T^2=0$. Similarly for  $S$, the restriction of $\alpha$ to $Y$.

Now say $v\in\Bbb R^4$. There exist $x\in X$, $y\in Y$ with $v=x+y$. So $$\alpha^2v=\alpha^2x+\alpha^2y=T^2x+S^2y=0.$$So $\alpha^2=0$, contradiction.

Comment: +1 This is neat. I was trying to describe how an invariant complement of ker $\alpha.$ would look like and get a contradiction.

Comment: @PVanchinathan Yeah, I was trying more or less that. Then I realized I wasn't sure how to show that one of $X$ and $Y$ must be $\ker\alpha$ and decided I needed to find something simpler...

Comment: All I know by Cayley Hamilton that every matrix  annihilates its characteristic polynomial i.e $P(T) = 0$ (where $T$ is the matrix corresponding to the linear transformation $\alpha$) and since the characteristic polynomial we obtained is $\lambda ^4$ then by Cayley Hamilton $T^4 = 0$. so I do not understand your usage of the theorem. Also why the minimal polynomial is a factor of $x^3$?

Comment: I do not understand this statement in your last line "it would follow that $\alpha^2=0$," could you clarify it please?

Comment: @Secretly I added a few details...

Comment: why in the third line from below $v \in \mathbb{R^3}$?

Comment: @Secretly Typo. Sorry/thanks...